# How do I disable the bounces effect of wkewbview in iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift

```
WKWebView. ScrollerView. Bounces = false
```

ios12 works but in ios14 doesn't work, how can I solve

Answer (score 0):

These worked for me,try

```
webView.scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = false
webView.scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
webView.scrollView.bounces = false
```